# Is there a way to change the organizer for Family Sharing?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, family-sharing

Once a family sharing plan is established is there anyway to change the "organizer" to another account?

Based on my research it looks like the only way to accomplish this is to disband the family sharing account and then recreate with a different account as an organizer. I am hesitant to do this as [some people have reported getting locked out of family sharing after disabling it](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1764723). Can anyone suggest any alternative means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the disband method and had no trouble recreating the family sharing group.

It's not ideal, but now it appears to be the only method.